# Wpf: Generic collection dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have created custom control with generic collection dependency property.
But whenever this property is changed from xaml, value in view model in setter is null.

CustomControl:

```
   public IList A       
   {
            get { return (IList)GetValue(AProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AProperty, value); }
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty AProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(A), typeof(IList), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(new List<object>()));
```

ViewModel:

```
  List<B> collectionB;
  public List<B> CollectionB
        {
            get { return collectionB; }
            set
            {
                if (collectionB == value) return;
                collectionB = value;
            }
        }
```

If I change type of CollectionB to List<object> it works fine.

Comment: You haven't shown us what exactly "*changed from xaml*" means. Is there a binding like `A="{Binding CollectionB, Mode=TwoWay}"`? And how does the control change the collection?

Comment: The binding was A="{Binding CollectionB, Mode=OneWayToSource}"

Comment: The default value (see my remarks in the answer) is of type `List<object>`. That can't be assigned to a source property of type `List<B>`. OneWayToSource is not a well-suited approach here. Do not set a default value at all and use a TwoWay Binding instead.

Comment: @AdamStawarek: Of course you can set an `IList` property to a `List<A>`. If the property is still `null` you are doing something wrong when you set it, or maybe you don't set it all. It's hard to say without some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

The most generic type of a collection property is `IEnumerable` - see for example the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property.

Also be aware that setting a non-null default value for a collection-type dependency property is problematic, because all instances of the owning class would by default operate on the same collection instance. Adding an element to the A property of one control would change the collection of all other control instances.

You should declare the property like this:

```
public IEnumerable A       
{
    get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(AProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty AProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(A), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(CustomControl));
```

In case you really need a non-null default value, add this to the control's constructor:

```
SetCurrentValue(AProperty, new List<object>());
```

---

Update: Using a `OneWayToSource` Binding of a collection type property like

```
<local:CustomControl A="{Binding CollectionB, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

can only work if the default value of `A` is assignment-compatible with the source property of the Binding, which does not hold true for `List<object>` and `List<B>`.

You should instead not set a default value at all, and instead use a TwoWay Binding

```
<local:CustomControl A="{Binding CollectionB, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

with

```
private List<B> collectionB = new List<B>();

public List<B> CollectionB
{
    get { return collectionB; }
    set { collectionB = value; }
}
```

or just

```
public List<B> CollectionB { get; set; } = new List<B>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately using IEnumerable instead of IList does not solve this issue and value is still null.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `IList<T>` does not implement `IList` so casting from one type to the other will fail.

If you want a binding with `A` then you must bind it to something that's also implementing `IList`

Comment: I've changed IList<B> to List<B> as the second one implements IList but unfortunately it didn't work either. Still it was good point so i'll update the question.